# How to host a Backend Server?

Tags: go, server

I created a backend application using golang which accept requests and send responses for my Android app which I also created. I'm able to use the server at home because we are connected to the same network. My question is how do I host the server so that I will be able to send requests anywhere. Is it possible to use hosting sites like hostgator? so it means that the ip of the server will be accessible to everyone? ex: 192.168.149.1:8888/api/getData. I hope this make sense, I have no experience in this cause I've always hosted my apps locally.

Comment: Please do some research into the existing cloud hosting vendors, they have documentation and some have free tiers which will help in any decision you make.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go) service. This service give you free plan for start and give you some advices about uploading your app. I used it with Java/Kotlin, it worked fine.

Comment: Works with go flawlessly too

Comment: Please do not answer opinion-based questions with opinionated answers. The question will soon be closed and deleted.